# Validate submitted form and display errors gracefully

Tags: express, mongoose, ejs, mongoose-schema

I am trying to validate user submitted form and display meaningful errors, but I have a lot of problems. First of all, my form (`event_form.ejs`):

```
<% if (typeof errors !== 'undefined') { %>
    <div class="message"><%= errors %></div>
<% } %> 

<form method="POST" action="/submit-create-event" id="create-event">
  <input type="text" class="title" name="title" placeholder="title">
  <input type="text" class="date" autocomplete="off" name="date" placeholder="date">
  <select class="type" name="type">
    <option value="road">Road</option>
    <option value="mtb">MTB</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="city" name="city" placeholder="city">
  <select class="level" name="level">
      <option value="beginner">Beginner</option>
      <option value="advanced">Advanced</option>
      <option value="pro">Pro</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="start-time timepicker" autocomplete="off" data-time-format="H:i" name="startTime" placeholder="start time">
  <input type="text" class="start_location" name="startLocation" placeholder="start location">
  <input type="text" class="distance" name="distance" placeholder="distance">
  <input type="submit" class="create-event-submit">
</form>
```

On submit, in my `eventController.js` I have function to handle submit.

```
//Helper function to handle event form submit.
module.exports.submitEventForm = function(req, res) {

  const event = new eventModel.event({
    title: req.body.title,
    date: req.body.date,
    type: req.body.type,
    city: req.body.city,
    level: req.body.level,
    start_time: req.body.startTime,
    start_location: req.body.startLocation,
    distance: req.body.distance
  });

  event.save(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      //I tried this, kinda works but pretty sure a bad practice
      res.render('forms/create_event_form', {errors: err})
    } else {
      res.render('status/success');
    }
  });
};
```

As you can see, on `event.save()` if I have errors, I `console.log()` them at the moment. What I tried doing was rendering once again my `event creation` form and displaying errors (as visible in my `.ejs` file). Pretty sure it should not be done like that.

This is my `model` file with one `validator`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var validate = require('mongoose-validator')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var titleValidator = [
  validate({
    validator: 'isAlphanumeric',
    message: 'Title should be alphanumeric'
  })
]

var eventSchema = new Schema({
  title: {type: String, required: true, validate: titleValidator},
  date: {type: String },
  type: {type: String },
  city: {type: String },
  level: {type: String },
  start_time: {type: String },
  start_location: {type: String },
  distance: {type: Number },
});

var Event = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);

module.exports.eventSchema = eventSchema;
module.exports.event = Event;
```

I created `titleValidator`, and if my form fails, it prints out something like this:

[image: Error message on incorrect tilte]

My questions is: **How can I properly send my `validator` message to the template and display it? How to handle multiple messages once more `validators` are created, as errors are not returned in `array` manner, meaning I cannot loop through them?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda found a solution. To make error messages more readable and usable, I used [Mongoose error helper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-error-helper). It prints out all error messages neatly. **However**, when getting package via `npm` there is a bug in code and a [pull request](https://github.com/syntagma/mongoose-error-helper/pull/2) is created for a solution, but was never merged. Just make that minor change manually.

I couldn't find another way of rendering the same form with errors, so I sticked to this:

```
event.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.render('forms/create_event_form', {errors: errorHelper(err, next)});
    } else {
      res.render('status/success');
    }
  });
```

and in my `.ejs` template I print out errors as follows:

```
<% if (typeof errors !== 'undefined') { 
   errors.forEach(function(err) { %>
    <div class="message"><%= err %></div>
<% })} %>
```

Hope this helps someone, cheers.